# How to get only text in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There is a list now i'm trying to get list data in array using push but there is getting only classes instead of text. How to fix this?

My Code:-

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    let tags = [];
    tags = $('span.tag').each(function() {
      tags.push($(this).text());
    });
    console.log(tags);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="tag label label-primary">test</span>
<span class="tag label label-primary">new</span>


<button>Get Value</button>
```

ThankYou!

Comment: Why are you pushing onto the jQuery collection?`tags = $('span.tag')` is setting tags to the items you just found! do not do that.  you are also reinventing https://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: i need only text in array like this ["AIEEE","IIT","AIIMS"]

Comment: You made an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected the targets using `$('span.tag')`. You have to loop it corrctly.

You can either loop through each elements in the selector and access the text with `$(node).text()` where `node` is the each element in the selector.

You can run a `each` and push that to `tags` array with

```
$('span.tag').each(function (index, node) {
    tags.push($(node).text());
});
```

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        let tags = [];
        $('span.tag').each(function (index, node) {
            tags.push($(node).text());
        });
        console.log(tags);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="tag label label-primary">test</span>
<span class="tag label label-primary">new</span>


<button>Get Value</button>
```

**`Array.map` implementation**

```js
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        const tags = Array.from($('span.tag').map((index, node) => $(node).text()));
        console.log(tags);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tag label label-primary">test</span>
<span class="tag label label-primary">new</span>

<button>Get Value</button>
```